# Configure Websphere MQConnectionFactory with proxy server in JBoss

Tags: java, authentication, jboss, proxy, ibm-mq

I want to connect to a WSMQ queue (running on a server outside of my company network) from a JBoss AS server (5.1) using the resource-adapter supplied by Websphere MQ (7).

I set up a connection factory and want to configure it to use our proxy-server, which is needed to connect to a machine outside the network. Our proxy-server requires authentication.

I found the (`MQConnectionFactory`) properties `proxyHostName` and `proxyPort` but no means to add authentication (username / password).

The Java properties `http.proxyHost` etc. don't make any difference, which makes sense since JMS doesn't use http.

Configuring the `socksProxyHost`, `socksProxyPort`, `java.net.socks.username` and `java.net.socks.password` properties also has no effect.

I'm at a loss here, how can I connect from JBoss AS to a remote WSMQ queue using a proxy server which requires authentication?

Answer (score 7):

You need to wrap the MQConnectionFactory with org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter

```
    MQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new MQConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setTransportType(1);
    connectionFactory.setHostName("localhost");
    connectionFactory.setPort(1415);
    connectionFactory.setQueueManager("DEV.QMGR");

    UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter connectionFactoryAdapter=new UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter();
    connectionFactoryAdapter.setTargetConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    connectionFactoryAdapter.setUsername("myusername");
    connectionFactoryAdapter.setPassword("mypassword");

    JmsComponent jmsComponent = new JmsComponent();
    jmsComponent.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactoryAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate an MQQueueConnectionFactory,
you have two methods to create a QueueConnection instance, one does let you specify the userId and password.

```
String userId = "test";
String password = "password";
mqQueueConnectionFactory = new com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory();
QueueConnection queueConnection =
mqQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(userId,password);
```